# NSDictionary is always [0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have this implementation in my code:

```
@implementation vcLogin {
    Util *_Util;
    NSInteger _RowCount;
    NSDictionary *_Payload;
}
```

And in another function I'm trying to fill the NSDictionary:

```
_Payload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

But the value of the dictionary is always [0].

I have tested this code to see if it was working:

```
NSDictionary *tPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

And tPayload returns the 2 values that I'm expecting.

I have tried this:

```
NSDictionary *tPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
_Payload = [tPayload mutableCopy];
```

Or

```
NSDictionary *tPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
_Payload = tPayload;
```

Or

```
NSDictionary *tPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
[_Payload setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:tPayload];
```

I have done this before in an old Application and I'm almost sure that I have just declared in the implementation, and all the time the dictionary is null until I fill it, if I check the value in the viewDidLoad in my old app the value is null but in my new app is [0].

I don't know what I'm missing.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT 1:**

I have just realized that all my variables in the implementation are [0] when I stop the debugger in the viewDidLoad.

```
@implementation vcLogin {
    Util *_Util;
    NSInteger _RowCount;
    NSDictionary *_Payload;
}
```

Old App:

[image]

New App:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

As someone pointed in the comments I did a NSLog of the variable and is full with information, maybe my Xcode is having problems.

I'm going to continue, if i found the problem of the Xcode I will post an answer.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: try initialising the _Payload and then use it! Sory, is _Payload nil ?

Comment: @Mr.T I have tried that in the viewDidLoad _Payload = Nil and before and after the Nil the value is [0]

Comment: "And tPayload returns the 2 values that I'm expecting" Please show the actual NSLog output from this, and also the NSLog output from logging `_Payload`. Also please show more code context - the actual NSLog, the actual code in which you are doing all this, etc. Do not try to read any of this off the variables pane in the debugger; use NSLog and show us what you get.

Comment: The second screenshot points to a `Util` instance rather than an `NSDictionary`

Comment: @vadian yes because all of the variables are [0]

Comment: You could & should pass an error to `JSONObjectWithData`, and see if any trouble occurred during parsing.

Comment: @matt thanks for telling me to look for the NSLog, all the variables are full but for some reason my Xcode is not working properly

Comment: Try cleaning the project. If that does not work, try restarting Xcode.

Comment: I turned my advice into an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is merely an artifact of the way you are trying to look at your variables. You're using the "tooltips" feature. This is a very tricky feature, especially because it works *before* the variable has even been given a value — that is, it *shows* a value, even though the variable really has no value yet, and the value that it shows is nonsense. That's exactly your problem: you're pausing in `viewDidLoad` and using the tooltip, but that is way too soon: the variables have no value yet.

The reliable way to look at variable values is good old-fashioned caveman debugging, i.e. do an NSLog on your variable after you are sure that the variable has a value.

Comment: Actually, tooltips are high on my list of "Xcode features that are the Work Of The Devil". My advice: _never_ use them.

Answer (score -2):

Before using an NSDictionary, you need to init it. In objective-C, it's done like this:

```
NSDictionary *dConfiguration = [NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData` does that for you, it returns an initialised object, you don't need to allocate or initialise it before the call (which would just overwrite the one you allocated).